# redirect htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Im trying to some redirects with a site I inherited, I didnt build the original htaccess

Currently when I click in the about link in Google it just takes me a 404 landing page , whereas I want it to take me to about_us page...

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^showroom$ index.php?route=showroom/showroom [L]
RewriteRule ^blog$ index.php?route=blog/home [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^about$ https://www.example.ie/about_us/ [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep redirect rules before internal routing ones:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^about$ https://www.example.ie/about_us/ [R,L] 

RewriteRule ^showroom$ index.php?route=showroom/showroom [L]

RewriteRule ^blog$ index.php?route=blog/home [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, really I should have seen that given that other ones were before it :)